# Powershell Comparing Object String to Static String

Tags: string, powershell, loops, object

I'm new to coding, so apologies in advance for knowing just about nothing.

I'm trying to compare a property of a user object in Active Directory (SamAccountName) to a static string I put myself in the condition of an if statement. The purpose is to increase a count, $activeCount++, if 1 of 2 specific users gets passed through a loop.

Again, apologies for the horrendous coding, but with my limited knowledge here's what I've attempted.

```vbnet
$users = $null
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU="",OU="",DC="",DC=""" -Filter *
$activeCount = 0

ForEach($user in $users){
    $tempLast = Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties LastLogonDate | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastLogonDate
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Description $tempLast

    $currentmonth = (Get-Date).Month
    $currentmonth = $currentmonth.ToString()
    $templast = Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties Description | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Description

    if($templast -eq $null){
           Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Description "INQUIRE ACTIVITY"
    }
    else{
           $loginmonth = $tempLast.Substring(0,2)

           if(($user."SamAccountName" -eq "EXCEPTION1") -or ($user."SamAccountName" -eq "EXCEPTION2")){
           $activeCount++
           }

           if($currentmonth -like $loginmonth){
           Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Description "ACTIVE        |    $($tempLast)"
           $activeCount++
           }
           else{
           Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Description "INACTIVE    |    $($tempLast)"
           }
    }
    

}
```

I don't really post ever, and if you need more information please let me know. I've butchered out a bit of code because I think it's all bloat, but I will definitely add as necessary. I would love a solution, but more than that an understanding of what I'm doing wrong and why.

Comment: What is the goal ? What are you trying to accomplish with your code ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon So, there are 30 users in an Active Directory OU. I'm trying to run a script that parses every user through the loop to run an "active/inactive" test by checking if they've logged into their computer this month (task scheduler runs this on the the last day of the month), and also taking a count. Im accomplishing this by getting their lastlogondate and seeing if the substring (0-2 for the month) matches the current month. This more or less works until I reach someone who works in the company but doesnt use a computer.

Comment: In this case, there are 2 individuals who fall in that condition.  So i tried making an if statement to say if the $user being sent through the loop matches one of the two samaccountname that I typed in, then simply increase the count of active users by 1 (since they will not have a lastlogondate property). I hope this helps.

Comment: Just to be sure, you can force a string comparison: $user."SamAccountName".ToString() or [string]$user."SamAccountName". It should work also without the double quotes for the attribute... and it should already be a string so your problem maybe something else.

Comment: @ZivkoK Strangely enough I think that fixed it!